# Passing variables (table name,data) into python mysqld query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I am trying to pass the name of the table and information to be inserted into the table as parameters.  The query I have come up with is below:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO `%s` (title,link,description) VALUES(%%s,%%s,%%s)""" % (feed,title_xml,link_xml,description_xml)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "slicer_1.py", line 41, in <module>
    sql = """INSERT INTO `%s` (title,link,description) VALUES(%%s,%%s,%%s)""" %(feed,title_xml,link_xml,description_xml)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You have double `%%` on the last three `%s`.  This means that only the first `%s` will be substituted in the string substitution, which means you can only pass one value to be substituted.  Perhaps you meant to pass the other three to the `execute` call to be handled by the SQL library's safe substitution?  Either that or you need to make all four have just one `%` so they all get substituted in the first step.  (I'm not sure if things like MySQLdb let you parameterize `VALUES` data.)

Edit: If you take the second suggestion, you probably want to do it like this:

```
"""INSERT INTO `%s` (title,link,description) VALUES("%s","%s","%s")""" % (feed,title_xml,link_xml,description_xml)
```

Comment: Removed %% and made it % and the error I get now is----> Traceback (most recent call last):
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Phailin kills 23, mass evacuations save thousands,http://feedproxy.google.com/~r' at line 1")

Comment: @user2876777: Probably you need to quote the values in `VALUES`.

Comment: code changed to """INSERT INTO `%s` (title,link,description) VALUES(`%s`,`%s`,`%s`)""" % (feed,title_xml,link_xml,description_xml) output is ---> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'Cyclone Phailin: India Meteorological Department wins battle over forecasts' in 'field list'")

Comment: Thank you that worked, however, I am able to pass only 2 variables, title and link. When I edit it to add the third variable, I get the following error -->
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'0" height="1" src="http://ndtv.com.feedsportal.com/c/33805/f/606695/s/327d6dc5/s\' at line 1')